# How to install jpype1(from boilerpipe) library from python33?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, boilerpipe, jpype

I am trying to install python library boilerpipe i.e.

```
pip install boilerpipe
```

but i am getting error i.e

```
command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

So what can i do fot this error?